# Orthophotos of Athens, Greece

Tags: europe, aerial-photography

I'm looking for orthophotos of Athens, Greece to measure forest development (raster data).

Is there any open source for such material? I'm looking for orthophotos dating back to 1980s if possible...

If there is also sensor data (infrared/near infrared) taken by planes that would be helpful too.

Comment: Have you had any luck contact the Universities in Greece there ?  How about the City of Athens GIS department ?  Those are where you need to start with.  And give me details what you need from an orthophotos ? Example, what year ?  BW or color .....